# issue in implementing Leah's PullRefreshTableViewController

Tags: objective-c

I have implemented `PullRefreshTableViewController` with some classes that take no delegates, and it works well.
However, I find it difficult to implement it in my project, because I am already implementing some delegates. How can I include delegates and the `PullRefreshTableViewController` on the same line?

My Code:

```
myFeedController.h :-
@interface myFeedController : UIViewController<FBRequestDelegate ,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,ASIHTTPRequestDelegate>{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i got the answer...

When you want to use PULL TO REFRESH in a `viewController` class inheriting `UITableView` only, ie no delegates, use LEAH's PULL TO REFRESH classes.

Where as when your class has already inheriting different delegates such as `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource`, `ASIHTTPRequestDelegate`, etc... then you should go for `EGORefreshTableHeaderView` classes.